# What is the difference in usage and nuance between "se targuer" and "se vanter"?

Tags: sens, usage

I would use both "se targuer" and "se vanter" in saying the following, for instance, even if leaning towards "se targuer" a little bit:

> Peu de gens peuvent **se targuer** de pouvoir discuter d'égal à égal avec Trump.
>
> Peu de gens peuvent **se vanter** de pouvoir discuter d'égal à égal avec Trump.

As for the following two constructions, on the other hand, the use of "se targuer" seems odd, if not impossible:

> Ce n’est pas pour **me vanter**, mais ...
>
> Sans vouloir **me vanter**, ...

So there must be some differences to take note of between "se targuer" and "se vanter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Se vanter* is to say/pretend anything that makes you appear good, or better than you are. One can *se vanter* of having done something, being something, owning something, ... anything you want.

*Se targuer* would be more about a quality, a property, an ability you have. However the nuance is slight because one can consider that having done something proves a quality or an ability, and then *se targuer* can be used.

*Se targuer* might be more about showing an extra value, focusing on the added value more than on what brought it, while *se vanter* can focus on either a value or an action. In the end the idea is the same though.

If you look at etymology, *targuer* comes from *targe* which was a shield (definitely an extra value in a battle). *Vanter* comes from latin *vanus* = *vain*.

*Note : [This answer could just be my opinion, I could'nt find any proof of this nuance while I found many counterexamples... But it's often the problem with nuances]*

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez : merci d'avoir supprimé le h de étymologie, erreur qui n'a rien à voir avec l'éthylisme je vous assure :). En ce qui concerne la mise en forme _comme ceci_ plutôt que `comme cela`, y a-t-il une règle de formatage des réponses écrite quelque part ?

Answer (score 0):

***(Se) targuer*** can only be used in limited contexts.

- It is literary while ***vanter*** can be used in all registers.
- It needs to be pronominal, we can't ***<s>targuer quelque chose</s>*** but we can ***vanter quelque chose***.
- It needs to have a complement, "***Il se vante.***" is possible but "*<s>**Il se targue.**</s>*" is not.

Comment: Hi. How does "s'enorgueillir" compare to thse two?